# One asynchronous thread per task?

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, asynchronous, task

My application currently has a list of "tasks" (Each task consists of a function - That function can be as simple as printing something out but also way more complex) which gets looped through. (Additional note: Most tasks send a packet after having been executed) As some of these tasks could take quite some time, I thought about using a different, asynchronous thread for each task, thus letting run all the tasks concurrently.

Would that be a smart thing to do or not?
One problem is that I can't possibly know the amount of tasks beforehand, so it could result in quite a few threads being created, and I read somewhere that each different hardware has it's limitations. I'm planing to run my application on a raspberry pi, and I think that I will always have to run between 5 and 20 tasks.

Also, some of the tasks have a lower "priority" of running that others.

Should I just run the important tasks first and then the less important ones? (Problem here is that if the sum of the time needed for all tasks together exceeds the time that some specific, important task should be run, my application won't be accurate anymore) Or implement everything in asynchronous threads? Or just try to make everything a little bit faster by only having the "packet-sending" in an asynchronous thread, thus not having to wait until the packets actually get sent?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenMP  (openmp.org)

Comment: @WilliamJones Thanks, I'll give it a read. But I think that right now my problem is still too theoretical to already be choosing a library: First I need to know if what I want to do is possible, or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of questions you will need to ask yourself before you can reasonably design a solution.

1. Do you wish to limit the number of concurrent tasks?
2. Is it possible that in future the number of concurrent tasks will increase in a way that you cannot predict today?

... and probably a whole lot more.

If the answer to any of these is "yes" then you have a few options:

- A producer/consumer queue with a fixed number of threads draining the queue (not recommended IMHO)
- Write your tasks as asynchronous state machines around an event dispatcher such as `boost::io_service` (this is much more scalable).

If you know it's only going to be 20 concurrent tasks, you'll probably get away with `std::async`, but it's a sloppy way to write code.

Comment: (1) Personally I don't want to limit them. The hardware is what limits them, I guess. (2) The number of concurrent tasks can't really increase much as the number of tasks is also limited by the hardware. And why would it be a sloppy way to write code? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The number of concurrent threads allowed is undefined in the c++ standard. There is also no (portable) way to query the system for the thread limit. This argues for an approach where the number of threads available to the program is provided by the environment (confit file, command line etc). This then argues for an asynchronous task-based approach since we're then not constrained by an arbitrary thread limit.

Comment: Well, if you forget about the programming-aspect itself, I thought that how many threads you can run concurrently depended very much on the hardware? And since I'm planing to run my application on a very small PC, like a RaspberryPi, I'm really not sure if 20 concurrent threads isn't way too much.

Comment: In the end the answer (if anywhere) will be in the documentation of your std library implementation and/or the os docs. In my testing on linux and OS X I started having problems after launching about 200 threads.